# React Hook Form - Does not set dependent select field value properly in edit mode

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hook-form

I am implementing a form in react using react hook form, The form has two select fields `country` and `states`.
Second field changes the option based on the selection in first field.

Please see the below sandbox for more details

Creating/submitting the record works perfectly fine.

**The problem is**:
 In edit, when I pre populate the values in the form using setValue(), it does not set the second dropdown(`state` select in the sandbox below) values on the UI  but it shows that it has set the value to the field(see in the console for field `state`).

[CodeSandBox] https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-murdock-h0lbsp?file=/src/App.js

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Open this sandbox in the browser.
2. Click on the `SET ALL VALUES` button.
3. See the blank value in states select

Also, Whats the **best way to populate** a form like this, i.e. in `defaultsValues` or `useEffect`?

What am I missing here, so putting it for the experts here.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is about `setValue`. This function does not trigger a re-render in most cases. You can use `reset` instead.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

Also, if you'd like to fill the form without any user interaction, use `reset` in `useEffect` with proper dependencies.

Lastly, If you'd like to have just them having initial values instead of being `undefined`, set `defaultValues`. It is also recommended in official documents:

> Important: You should provide a proper default value and avoid undefined.
> undefined is reserved for fallback from inline
> defaultValue/defaultChecked to hook level defaultValues. undefined value is conflicting with controlled component as default state

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform